# Sorting and updating a state property array? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I'm building a basic to-do list to learn `reactJS` and would like to put the checked items at the bottom of the list.

I have tried to use JavaScript's `.sort` the method at the end of the list before calling setState but it doesn't appear consistent. I've also tried doing this separately with `const x = Object.assign({},this.state)` but it provides the same result.

```
class App extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            todos: todosData
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(id){
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
                if(todo.id === id) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
                }
                return todo;
            }).sort((a,b) => (a.completed === b.completed)? 0 : a? -1 : 1)
            return{
                todos: updatedTodos
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Am I using this function wrong? Or perhaps I am missing something else?

Thank-you in advance for any help!

Comment: Won't `a? -1 : 1` always return `-1`?

Comment: @ray hatfield, if a === false and b === true it should return 1 shouldn't it?

Comment: But `a` and `b` are the todo objects, not `true/false`. Objects are truthy in js. So unless `a` is null (or undefined or 0) your expression is always going to return `-1`. Maybe you meant `a.completed ? -1 : 1`?

Comment: You are completely correct! Thank-you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Well, my critique would be that you're doing too many things inline. `map` does give you a new array, so I'm assuming that's fine (`setState` would acknowledge a change if the wrapper is a different reference), but the order of operations on your last line is probably what's causing issues.

`.sort((a,b) => (a.completed === b.completed)? 0 : a? -1 : 1)`

I would try to put that in blocks of curly braces, and you might want to check `a.completed`. I think the main issue is that it's evaluating your `(a,b) => (a.completed === b.completed)` as a truthy thing